# Animation shows default div

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-position

The animation works but I cannot get the `sidebar` to disappear off-canvas before the animation starts. The `sidebar` is always there. How to get the `sidebar` hidden in the left and only appear with the animation, that is when you click `Slide`? I tried `display: none` but then the animation does not work anymore.

```css
input+label+#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
}

input:checked+label+#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: appear 1s;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    right: 1000px;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="slide" name="slide" />
<label for="slide">Slide</label>
<nav id="sidebar">
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animations are good for making complex transitions to different states, but since you're simply toggling between "on" and "off", a transition would be a better candidate.

The default style of `#sidebar` should be hidden. You can do that by transforming it out of the screen. Then when the input is checked, transform it back into the screen.

```css
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d0d0d0;
  translate: -100% 0;
  transition: translate 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked ~ #sidebar {
  translate: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="slide" name="slide" />
<label for="slide">Slide</label>

<nav id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#sidebar {
  transform: translateX(-1000px);
}

input:checked~#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: appear 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="slide" name="slide" />
<label for="slide">Slide</label>
<nav id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Вut better use little js.

```js
const open = document.querySelector('.open');
const close = document.querySelector('.close');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#sidebar');

open.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.add('active');
  open.disabled = true;
});
close.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.remove('active');
  open.disabled = false;
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: .3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  transform: translate(0);
}
```

```html
<button class="open">Open</button>
<nav id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, I don’t understand why JS is needed in this case, and why it should be better. Could you add a bit more explanation to your answer?

Comment: Of course. Using your method, elements are formed in the code that do not carry any semantic meaning. In addition, if your site is used by people with visual impairments, for example, they will not be able to understand the navigation of site navigation by ear. There are also problems for people who are used to using the keyboard to navigate the site.